# Split Json Arrays based on length

Tags: c#, json

I need to encrypt a JSON array using GPG which when after length exceeds above 2083 characters, I need to split the JSON array which needs to be below 2083 characters.

To achieve this I will first encrypt the array and check its length for below 2083, If it it exceeds I will split the array to multiple arrays and then encrypt.

What is the better way of doing this?

for eg:

```
var a = new List<int> { 1,2,3 etc};
```

When I encrypt this array, just consider the string will be something like this

```
hQEMA%2Fgo0kYbZeCoAQf8DDemzoWdhq97ULWXvTw4v1fFMq%2F%2BO9z%2FYClDvON
```

And suppose if the above string exceeds 2083 chars, I will split the array something like below and then encrypt again.

```
var a = new List<int> { 1,2}; 
var b = new List<int> { 3, 4}; 
var c = new List<int> { 5, 6 etc.};
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a method like so and call it recursively. Note the method is also generic so that it is not constrained to `List<int>`, remove that if it is not necessary for your situation.

```
private const int maxLength = 2083;
public List<string> EncryptList<T>(List<T> list)
{
    List<string> encryptedLists = new List<string>();

    string encrypted = PerformEncryption();
    if (encrypted.Length > maxLength)
    {
        encryptedLists.AddRange(EncryptList<T>(list.Take(list.Count / 2).ToList()));
        encryptedLists.AddRange(EncryptList<T>(list.Skip(list.Count / 2).ToList())); 
    }
    else
    {
        encryptedLists.Add(encrypted);
    }

    return encryptedLists;
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code so the part inside of the if statement might not work correctly.

Comment: ist.Count / 2 - What will happen if it is again above 2083 chars ?? Also you're adding in the same list.

Comment: it calls itself recursively in the `AddRange` parts and I`m returning a list of the encrypted strings for you to do what yopu want with